# Sharing code between service worker & preact app

Tags: service-worker, preact

I am building a web-app using preact+redux. Some of the heavy lifting in being done in the service worker. As part of this logic I want to generate redux actions from the service worker. How can I share the common action creator code between the app & the service worker?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you try this work around:

1. Create Event emitter Client   (https://github.com/facebook/emitter)
2. Connect service worker with your event emitter Client
3. Create you component and subscribe to the right events

Create your own event emitter:

http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html#.Wxpc_jNKhsM

Listen events from components:

https://medium.com/netscape/buid-simple-react-apps-using-event-emitters-7a46554f56cd

Post Message:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I am using postMessage to communicate from sw to main. And event emitting & receiving is not the issue. The issue is that I want to share the action creation code for the main app with the sw code. The sw code does not go through transpilation.

Comment: @SaurabhGarg did you find a solution?